# Displays unwanted character while converting from QDataStream to QChar

Tags: c++, qt

I have a code as below

```
QByteArray bla("abcde");    
QDataStream ds(bla.right(bla.size()-1));
QChar c;
ds>>c;
qDebug()<<c; // It prints '?' instead of 'b'
```

It prints out b if I change the code as

```
qint8 c; 
ds>>c; 
qDebug()<<QChar(c); // It now prints 'b'.
```

It's ok for a single character suppose, I have a lot of characters then I need to make a loop and cast every single of them . Please suggest a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

`ds>>c;` equals `ds>>c.unicode();`, which has type `ushort &`. While QByteArray contains `char`s.

The correct way to converting `QBytaArray` to a sequence of `QChar` would be:

```
QByteArray bla("abcde");
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForLocale();
const QString string = codec->toUnicode(bla);
foreach (const QChar &c, string) {
    qDebug() << c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But suppose a case that a QByteArray has to be transformed to QDataStream and then proceeded. In that case what should be done ? For example  how many chars from QByteArray from left or right are to be printed are unkown and the parameter is  passed as a int in a function

Comment: @user3421760 Why do you need exactly `QChar`? What's wrong with reading `char`?